Await inside if block not waiting
I am loading some data from a DB table using sequelize and caching it in an in-memory object with a TTL so I don't keep reading from the DB over and over again.
// ffm.ts
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import { State } from 'src/db/models/geo/state';

export class FFMStates {
  private static lastRefreshed = new Date(0); // Initialize to start of epoch

  private static TTL = 60 * 60; // 1 hour

  public static DATA: Record<number, Array<string>>;

  public static async load() {
    FFMStates.lastRefreshed = new Date();
    const currentYear = FFMStates.lastRefreshed.getFullYear();

    const results = await State.findAll({
      where: {
        year: { [Op.gte]: currentYear - 2 }, // load 3 or 4 latest years
        ffm: true,
      },
      order: [
        ['year', 'ASC'],
        ['code', 'ASC'],
      ],
    });

    FFMStates.DATA = results.reduce((acc: Record<number, string[]>, state) => {
      if (!acc[state.year]) {
        acc[state.year] = [];
      }
      acc[state.year].push(state.code);
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

  public static async get() {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - FFMStates.lastRefreshed.getTime()) / 1000 > FFMStates.TTL) {
      await FFMStates.load();
    }
    return FFMStates.DATA;
  }
}

I am then using this module as follows:
import { FFMStates } from 'src/constants/health/ffm';

const ffmStates = await FFMStates.get();
const currentYear = ffmStates[this.year]; // This throws an error the first time this code runs because ffmStates is undefined

I tried debugging this with console.log() statements. It seems that when FFMStates.get() is called the first time, my code starts to run FFMStates.load() but does not await it and immediately executes the next line after the if block and returns FFMStates.DATA which is undefined at this point. I am not sure why await FFMStates.load() does not wait.

How often are you calling FFMStates.get()? If you call it twice in a row, the second call might see the updated FFMStates.lastRefreshed already while load is still running.

Yes, the second call gets the result, but I don't want the first call to fail.

"This throws an error the first time this code runs because ffmStates is undefined". What do you mean "first time"? You only called it once.

@SunnyPro It's the other way round. The first call works and returns the result (after some time), it's the second call (though the one that returns earlier) that fails. And the problem is that the calls are concurrent, the second call happened before the first call even completed.

I can't see how the code, as presented, would cause the error. I can only see that the error will occur the second (and subsequent) time you call .get() when those subsequent calls are within the time it takes to execute State.findAll({
i.e. if that takes 1 second for .findAll to get a result, then FFMStates.DATA will be undefined for that time, but FFMStates.lastRefreshed will have been updated. Therefore, any calls to .get() within that 1 second time period will return the still undefined .DATA
Try with the following changes.
To your class, add
private static inflight: Promise<any> | null = null;

at the end of .load, add
FFMStates.inflight = null;

change .get() like so:
public static async get() {
  if (FFMStates.inflight || (new Date().getTime() - FFMStates.lastRefreshed.getTime()) / 1000 > FFMStates.TTL) {
    if (!FFMStates.inflight) {
      FFMStates.inflight = FFMStates.load();
    }
    await FFMStates.inflight;
  }
  return FFMStates.DATA;
}


An alternate fix is to make FFMStates.DATA a Promise
public static DATA: Promise<Record<number, Array<string>>>;

change .load to return the results.reduce
return results.reduce((acc: Record<number, string[]>, state: {year:number, code:string}) => {

and change .get as follows:
public static async get() {
  if ((new Date().getTime() - FFMStates.lastRefreshed.getTime()) / 1000 > FFMStates.TTL) {
    // DO NOT USE await here
    FFMStates.DATA = FFMStates.load();
  }
  return FFMStates.DATA;
}

Arguably cleaner, but does require changing .DATA to a Promise, which may impact other code you may have not shown.
